# PDFBox: How to get a PDRectangle from a TextPosition

Tags: pdfbox

I have a requirement of replacing certain phrases in existing PDFs with hyperlinks. For example, "One advantage of using the Java language is the availability of man-power" should get processed to "One advantage of using [the Java language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) is the availability of man-power."

For this, I created a Processor class extending [PDFTextStripper](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.html). By overriding `processTextPosition`, I was able to get the [TextPosition](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/TextPosition.html) of all the characters. But I am unable to know how to get a [PDRectangle](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/common/PDRectangle.html) from a TextPosition, which will help me build a [PDAnnotationLink](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/annotation/PDAnnotationLink.html). I tried the combinations of x, y properties, but am missing the location. Needing some help. Thank you.

Sanjay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this:

```
rectangle.setLowerLeftX(position.getTextPos().getXPosition());
rectangle.setLowerLeftY(position.getTextPos().getYPosition() - 2); // 2 as cushion
rectangle.setUpperRightX(rectangle.getLowerLeftX() + position.getWidthDirAdj());
rectangle.setUpperRightY(rectangle.getLowerLeftY() + 12 /*
    ideally it should be position.getHeightDir()?
    but my sample PDF yielded a negative figure for this */);
```